# Optimizing using Pandas DataFrame

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

I have the following function that loads a csv into a data frame then does some calculations.  It takes about 4-5 minutes to do calculation on the csv with a little over 100,000 lines.  I was hoping there is a faster way.

```
def calculate_adeck_errors(in_file):
    print(f'Starting Data Calculations: {datetime.datetime.now().strftime("%I:%M%p on %B %d, %Y")}')
    pd.set_option('display.max_columns', 12)

    # read in the raw csv
    adeck_df = pd.read_csv(in_file)
    #print(adeck_df)

    #extract only the carq items and remove duplicates
    carq_data = adeck_df[(adeck_df.MODEL == 'CARQ') & (adeck_df.TAU == 0)].drop_duplicates(keep='last')
    #print(carq_data)

    #remove carq items from original
    final_df = adeck_df[adeck_df.MODEL != 'CARQ']
    #print(final_df)

    row_list = []
    for index, row in carq_data.iterrows():
        position_time = row['POSDATETIME']
        for index, arow in final_df.iterrows():
            if arow['POSDATETIME'] == position_time:
                # match, so do calculations
                storm_id = arow['STORMID']
                model_base_time = arow['MODELDATETIME']
                the_hour = arow['TAU']
                the_model = arow['MODEL']
                point1 = float(row['LAT']), float(row['LON'])
                point2 = float(arow['LAT']), float(arow['LON'])
                if arow['LAT'] == 0.0:
                    dist_error = None
                else:
                    dist_error = int(round(haversine(point1, point2, miles=True)))

                if arow['WIND'] != 0:
                    wind_error = int(abs(int(row['WIND']) - int(arow['WIND'])))
                else: wind_error = None

                if arow['PRES'] != 0:
                    pressure_error = int(abs(int(row['PRES']) - int(arow['PRES'])))
                else:
                    pressure_error = None

                lat_carq = row['LAT']
                lon_carq = row['LON']
                lat_model = arow['LAT']
                lon_model = arow['LON']
                wind_carq = row['WIND']
                wind_model = arow['WIND']
                pres_carq = row['PRES']
                pres_model = arow['PRES']

                row_list.append([storm_id, model_base_time, the_model, the_hour, lat_carq, lon_carq, lat_model, lon_model, dist_error,
                             wind_carq, wind_model, wind_error, pres_carq, pres_model, pressure_error])

    result_df = pd.DataFrame(row_list)
    result_df = result_df.where((pd.notnull(result_df)), None)
    result_cols = ['StormID', 'ModelBasetime', 'Model' , 'Tau',
               'LatCARQ', 'LonCARQ', 'LatModel', 'LonModel', 'DistError',
               'WindCARQ', 'WindModel','WindError',
               'PresCARQ', 'PresModel','PresError']

    result_df.columns = result_cols

calculate_adeck_errors(infile)
```

To clarify what I'm doing:

1. The CARQ entries are the control (actual).
2. The other models are the guesses.
3. I'm comparing the control (CARQ) to the guesses to see what their errors are.
4. The basis of the comparison is the MODELBASETIME = POSBASETIME
5. A sample file I'm processing is here:  http://vortexweather.com/downloads/adeck/aal062018.csv

I was hoping there is a faster way than I'm doing it, or another pandas method besides `iterrows`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**This code takes about 10 seconds to run your entire dataset!**

The code looks very similar to what you have written, with the exception that all of the operations within the main_function have been vectorized.  See [Fast, Flexible, Easy and Intuitive: How to Speed Up Your Pandas Projects](https://realpython.com/fast-flexible-pandas/#pandas-apply)

[2018-09-13_adeck_error_calculations.ipynb](https://github.com/trenton3983/stack_overflow/tree/master/complete_solutions)

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import datetime
from haversine import haversine


def main_function(df, row):
    """
    The main difference here is that everything is vectorized
    Returns: DataFrame
    """
    
    df_new = pd.DataFrame()
    df_storage = pd.DataFrame()
    
    pos_datetime = df.POSDATETIME.isin([row['POSDATETIME']])  # creates a Boolean map
    array_len = len(pos_datetime)
    new_index = pos_datetime.index

    df_new['StormID'] = df.loc[pos_datetime, 'STORMID']
    df_new['ModelBaseTime'] = df.loc[pos_datetime, 'MODELDATETIME']
    df_new['Model'] = df.loc[pos_datetime, 'MODEL']
    df_new['Tau'] = df.loc[pos_datetime, 'TAU']
    
    # Distance
    df_new['LatCARQ'] = pd.DataFrame(np.full((array_len, 1), row['LAT']), index=new_index).loc[pos_datetime, 0]
    df_new['LonCARQ'] = pd.DataFrame(np.full((array_len, 1), row['LON']), index=new_index).loc[pos_datetime, 0]
    df_new['LatModel'] = df.loc[pos_datetime, 'LAT']
    df_new['LonModel'] = df.loc[pos_datetime, 'LON']

    
    def calc_dist_error(row):
        return round(haversine((row['LatCARQ'], row['LonCARQ']), (row['LatModel'], row['LonModel']), miles=True)) if row['LatModel'] != 0.0 else None
    
    df_new['DistError'] = df_new.apply(calc_dist_error, axis=1)
    
    # Wind
    df_new['WindCARQ'] = pd.DataFrame(np.full((array_len, 1), row['WIND']), index=new_index).loc[pos_datetime, 0]
    df_new['WindModel'] = df.loc[pos_datetime, 'WIND']
    df_storage['row_WIND'] = pd.DataFrame(np.full((array_len, 1), row['WIND']), index=new_index).loc[pos_datetime, 0]
    df_storage['df_WIND'] = df.loc[pos_datetime, 'WIND']
    
    
    def wind_error_calc(row):
        return (row['row_WIND'] - row['df_WIND']) if row['df_WIND'] != 0 else None

    df_new['WindError'] = df_storage.apply(wind_error_calc, axis=1)
    
    # Air Pressure
    df_new['PresCARQ'] = pd.DataFrame(np.full((array_len, 1), row['PRES']), index=new_index).loc[pos_datetime, 0]
    df_new['PresModel'] = df.loc[pos_datetime, 'PRES']
    df_storage['row_PRES'] = pd.DataFrame(np.full((array_len, 1), row['PRES']), index=new_index).loc[pos_datetime, 0]
    df_storage['df_PRES'] = df.loc[pos_datetime, 'PRES']

    
    def pres_error_calc(row):
        return abs(row['row_PRES'] - row['df_PRES']) if row['df_PRES'] != 0 else None

    df_new['PresError'] = df_storage.apply(pres_error_calc, axis=1)
    
    del(df_storage)

    return df_new


def calculate_adeck_errors(in_file):
    """
    Retruns: DataFrame
    """
    print(f'Starting Data Calculations: {datetime.datetime.now().strftime("%I:%M:%S%p on %B %d, %Y")}')
    pd.set_option('max_columns', 20)
    pd.set_option('max_rows', 300)
          
    # read in the raw csv
    adeck_df = pd.read_csv(in_file)
    adeck_df['MODELDATETIME'] = pd.to_datetime(adeck_df['MODELDATETIME'], format='%Y-%m-%d %H:%M')
    adeck_df['POSDATETIME'] = pd.to_datetime(adeck_df['POSDATETIME'], format='%Y-%m-%d %H:%M')
    
    #extract only the carq items and remove duplicates
    carq_data = adeck_df[(adeck_df.MODEL == 'CARQ') & (adeck_df.TAU == 0)].drop_duplicates(keep='last')    
    print('Len carq_data: ', len(carq_data))
          
    #remove carq items from original
    final_df = adeck_df[adeck_df.MODEL != 'CARQ']
    print('Len final_df: ', len(final_df))
                  
    df_out_new = pd.DataFrame()

    for index, row in carq_data.iterrows():

        test_df = main_function(final_df, row)  # function call

        df_out_new = df_out_new.append(test_df, sort=False)
        

    df_out_new = df_out_new.reset_index(drop=True)
    df_out_new = df_out_new.where((pd.notnull(df_out_new)), None)
    
    print(f'Finishing Data Calculations: {datetime.datetime.now().strftime("%I:%M:%S%p on %B %d, %Y")}')
    return df_out_new

in_file = 'aal062018.csv'

df = calculate_adeck_errors(in_file)
>>>Starting Data Calculations: 02:18:30AM on September 13, 2018
>>>Len carq_data:  56
>>>Len final_df:  137999
>>>Finishing Data Calculations: 02:18:39AM on September 13, 2018

print(len(df))
>>>95630

print(df.head(20))
```

Comment: Your Pandas Kung-Fu is strong.  Many thanks for the insight and help.  Very much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you are creating two dataframes out of the same dataframe, and then processing them. Two things that may cut your time.

First, you are iterating over both dataframes and checking for a condition:

```
for _, row in carq_data.iterrows():
    for _, arow in final_df.iterrows():
        if arow['POSDATETIME'] == row['POSDATETIME']:
            # do something by using both tables
```

This is essentially an implementation of a join. You are joining `carq_data` with `final_df` on `'POSDATETIME'`.

As a first step, you should merge the tables:

```
merged = carq_data.merge(final_df, on=['POSDATETIME'])
```

At this point you will get multiple rows for each similar `'POSDATETIME'`. In the below, let's assume column `b` is `POSDATETIME`:

```
>>> a
   a   b
0  1  11
1  1  33
>>> b
   a  b
0  1  2
1  1  3
2  1  4
>>> merged = a.merge(b, on=['a'])
>>> merged
   a  b_x  b_y
0  1   11    2
1  1   11    3
2  1   11    4
3  1   33    2
4  1   33    3
5  1   33    4
```

Now, to do your conditional calculations, you can use the `apply()` function.

First, define a function:

```
def calc_dist_error(row):
    return int(round(haversine(row['b_x'], row['b_y'], miles=True))) if row['a'] != 0.0 else None
```

Then apply it to every row:

```
merged['dist_error'] = merged.apply(calc_dist_error, axis=1)
```

Continuing my small example:

```
>>> merged['c'] = [1, 0, 0, 0, 2, 3]
>>> merged
   a  b_x  b_y  c
0  1   11    2  1
1  1   11    3  0
2  1   11    4  0
3  1   33    2  0
4  1   33    3  2
5  1   33    4  3
>>> def foo(row):
...     return row['b_x'] - row['b_y'] if row['c'] != 0 else None
...
>>> merged['dist_error'] = merged.apply(foo, axis=1)
>>> merged
   a  b_x  b_y  c  dist_error
0  1   11    2  1         9.0
1  1   11    3  0         NaN
2  1   11    4  0         NaN
3  1   33    2  0         NaN
4  1   33    3  2        30.0
5  1   33    4  3        29.0
```

This should help you reduce run time (see also [this](https://engineering.upside.com/a-beginners-guide-to-optimizing-pandas-code-for-speed-c09ef2c6a4d6) for how to check using `%timeit`). Hope this helps!